# Angular 4 google maps how to initialize the map with street view

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am using `Angular Google Maps (AGM): https://angular-maps.com/`
I want to initialize the map with street view depending on latitude and longitude

My code Now:

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  </agm-map>
```

How I can do that?

Comment: are you still unable to initialize your map?

Comment: @henrisycip yes, in street view mode

Comment: https://ng2-ui.github.io/map/#/map-with-streetview , refer this link it may help you ...